# <insert name of struct> was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, struct

http://pastebin.com/4gvcQm7P

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int GenerateID()
{
    static int nextID = 0;
    return nextID++;
}

void PrintInformation(Employee EmployeeName)
{
    cout << EmployeeName << "'s ID is: " << EmployeeName.ID << endl;
    cout << EmployeeName << "'s age is: " << EmployeeName.age << endl;
    cout << EmployeeName << "'s wage is: " << EmployeeName.wage << endl;
}

int main()
{

    struct Employee
    {
        int ID;
        int age;
        float wage;
    };

    Employee Dominic;
    Employee Jeffrey;

    Dominic.ID = GenerateID();
    Dominic.age = 22;
    Dominic.wage = 7.10;

    Jeffrey.ID = GenerateID();
    Jeffrey.age = 28;
    Dominic.wage = 7.10;

    PrintInformation(Dominic);
    PrintInformation(Jeffrey);

    return 0;
}

/*
C:\CBProjects\Practise\main.cpp|11|error: variable or field 'PrintInformation' declared void|
C:\CBProjects\Practise\main.cpp|11|error: 'Employee' was not declared in this scope|
C:\CBProjects\Practise\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\CBProjects\Practise\main.cpp|39|error: 'PrintInformation' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build finished: 3 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
*/
```

The above pastebin link shows the code I used and the build report. Following this report I attempted to forward declare the struct without including members and then there is an 'incomplete type' error.

What is the solution?

Edit: I'm using c++11

Edit 2: Here is what happens if I try to forward declare the struct, including the members:

http://pastebin.com/rrt4Yjes#

Comment: Are you using C++11 or C++03?

Comment: Obviously you need a forward-declaration.  Since `Employee` is a local class, I don't know how to write that forward-declaration, or if it's even possible.

Comment: Re Edit2:  That's not a forward declaration.  That is an entirely seperate declaration.  Now you have two things called `Employee` -- one is declared in global scope, and the other is declared within the scope of `main`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two solutions: Make `Employee` a non-local class/struct or make `PrintInformation` a template. For the first solution, just move `Employee` *before* `PrintInformation`. The second solution would be:

```
template< typename Employee >
void PrintInformation(const Employee& EmployeeName)
{
    cout << " EmployeeName's ID is: " << EmployeeName.ID << endl;
    cout << " EmployeeName's age is: " << EmployeeName.age << endl;
    cout << " EmployeeName's wage is: " << EmployeeName.wage << endl;
}
```

Note that in any case you don't want a copy of `Employee` just to print some information, hence make the parameter of `PrintInformation` a constant reference as shown above.

Comment: You can't use a local type as a template parameter in C++03 (`[C++03: 14.3.1/2]`), though you can in C++11. I know, the OP is writing C++11. But I thought it worth noting.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Worth to note, indeed. I sometimes forget there was a time before C++11... :D

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why I should make the parameter a constant, and I'm also not familiar with the '&' suffix. I have not been able to figure out the template solution either. I've managed to solve the problem the first way you suggested and also the first way kfsone suggested however.

Comment: Regarding templates though, there's a section dedicated to them further on in the tutorial I'm following so I'll get to that by myself.

Comment: @MilesBardan For the `const T&`: It means you refer to an instance of `T` (by adding the `&` which means "reference" in C++) and the `const` is added to say that you are not going to modify the parameter. This is something you should probably learn early. For the other part, you can skip the template-solution for now as in the context of what you are doing it is possible but not very common. Just use the non-local approach, learn about the required order of *declarations* and *definitions* and when to use a *forward declaration*. Good luck!

Comment: @MilesBardan: Because why not, frankly. And if you're not familiar with `&` then you probably ought to read the early chapters of your C++ book again...

Answer (score 2):

First piece of information in the error is the line number.

```
C:\CBProjects\Practise\main.cpp|11|error: variable or field 'PrintInformation' declared void|
```

Line 11. Lets look at line 11.

```
void PrintInformation(Employee EmployeeName)
```

This all looks valid, but what's an Employee? We don't find that out until line 21. Your function, PrintInformation wants to make use of the internal plumbing of PrintInformation so the function actually needs to know the full definition of the struct/class.

In addition to all this, you have very explicitly made Employee a private type of `main` by defining it inside the function. What you are *actually* declaring is `main::Employee`.

A few solutions:

Declare "Employee" in the same scope as PrintInformation, i.e. at the global scope at the top of the file after the includes etc.

Or make "PrintInformation" a member function of Employee.

```
struct Employee
{
    void PrintInformation()
    {
        std::cout << " Employee's ID is: " << ID << '\n';
        std::cout << " Employee's age is: " << age << '\n';
        std::cout << " Employee's wage is: " << wage << '\n';
    }
    ...
};

...

Dominic.PrintInformation();
```

Or implement operator<< (probably advanced for where you are right now).

I'd also like to point out an aspect of style that is lining you up for some serious headaches down stream: You're using the same UpperCamelCase for variables and types, but being inconsistent with types. It's going to benefit you if you teach yourself to prefix member variables with something and maintain consistent case early on:

```
struct Employee  // UpperCamel for types.
{
    int m_id;
    int m_age;
    float m_wage;
};
```

It now becomes very easy to separate local variables and types and member variables. This is going to become especially useful as you start to learn about member functions.

```
struct Employee  // UpperCamel for types.
{
    int m_id;
    std::string m_name;
    int m_age;
    float m_wage;

    Employee(const std::string& name, int age, float wage)
        : m_id(nextID++)
        , m_name(name)
        , m_age(age)
        , m_wage(wage)
    {}

    ...

};
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I got a solution by following your advice to make PrintInformation into a member function of Employee. I also switched the variable names to camelCase (right name?) whilst keeping Function/struct names in UpperCamel. I'm still working through the rest of the advice provided to me.\\Regarding the m_ prefix, I just stopped using the hungarian notation after reading http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html and figured I would only use it like Apps Hungarian where it is noticeably useful. Are member variables/functions one of those situations?

Comment: It's not really about hungarian, more about avoiding variable shadowing. Consider: `struct Foo { int i; Foo(int i) { i = i; } };`. There are various common ways to avoid this, some people prefix or postfix variables with an underscore (`struct Foo { int _i; Foo(int i) { _i = i; } };` but the most common by far is to use `m_` to denote members, `s_` to denote statics and `g_` to denote globals. I've seen people instead make function arguments distinct (`void printStuff(const Employee& employee_)`). For a full example see http://ideone.com/ID84oB

Answer (score 0):

1. You should declare `struct Employee` before using it in `PrintInformation()` or make `PrintInformation` a template (as @DanielFrey did).
2. Fix your `PrintInformation()` to following as you cannot directly print a `struct` data unless you overloading `<<` for the struct (check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719136/overloading-with-a-struct-no-class-cout-style) on how to do this).

   ```
   void PrintInformation(Employee EmployeeName)
   {
       cout << " EmployeeName's ID is: " << EmployeeName.ID << endl;
       cout << " EmployeeName's age is: " << EmployeeName.age << endl;
       cout << " EmployeeName's wage is: " << EmployeeName.wage << endl;
   }
   ```

Comment: Note that `Employee` is delcared as a local class.

Comment: Because `Employee` is a local class, I believe this answer is *incorrect*.

Comment: @JohnDibling The OP doesn't say the employee /has/ to be a local class

Comment: @TomTanner:  Well that's true, but this answer does not address the fact that it /is/ a local class as presented.  Step 1 here might be implying that it should be made a non-local class, but that is entirely not clear to me.  I'd like to see some clarification about that from hero