# Struct doesn't print with cout

Tags: c++, struct

I'm trying to print the structure in an array whose `int prejetih` member is highest.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Tekma {
    int prejetih;
};

Tekma najvec_kosev(Tekma tekme[]) {
    int maksi = 0, index = 0;
    for (int i = 0;i < 2;i++) {
        if (maksi < tekme[i].prejetih) {
            index = i;
            maksi = tekme[i].prejetih;
        }
    }
    return tekme[index];
}

void vpis(Tekma tekme[]) {
    for (int i = 0;i < 2;i++)
        cin >> tekme[i].prejetih;
}

int main() {
    Tekma tekme[2];
    vpis(tekme);
    cout << najvec_kosev(tekme);
}
```

The compiler reports

```
C++ no operator matches these operands 
operand types are: std::ostream << Tekma
```

over `cout << najvec_kosev(tekme);`

Comment: Which error `std::cout` throw?

Comment: `cout` doesn't know how to print a `Tekma`. You can overload `operator<<` Or `cout << najvec_kosev(tekme).prejetih;`

Comment: It throws a: `C++ no operator matches these operands            operand types are: std::ostream << Tekma` error

Comment: @TimHajdinjak, So, if you read the error message carefully, you could realize that you need to overload `operator<<` for your type.

Comment: This will also not work when all the numbers are negative. I would suggest you initialize like this: `int masksi = tekme[0].prejetih`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp what if I add more variables to the `Tekma` Structure. How would I then print all variables?

Comment: You'd print the additional variables in Tekma in your `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Tekma const&);` routine.

Comment: Use `std::vector` to store all structs and loop over it. You are using a C style array with fixed size.

Comment: Potential duplicate: [overloading "<<" with a struct (no class) cout style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719136/overloading-with-a-struct-no-class-cout-style)

Comment: If you want a `struct` type that YOU have defined to be output with the streaming (`<<`) operator, then you need to define an appropriate `operator<<()` function that does the streaming.   Most basic/introductory texts on C++ describe how you can do this.    There is no magic in C++ that will define such a capability for you - only you can specify how a class that you define should be output (or input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here using a solution with `std::vector` and fixing your cout problem:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Tekma {
    int prejetih;
};

Tekma najvec_kosev(vector<Tekma>& tekme) {
    Tekma lowest = tekme[0]
    for(auto& t : tekme) {
        if(lowest.prejetih < t.prejetih) {
            lowest = t;
        }
    }
    return lowest ;
}

void vpis(vector<Tekma>& tekme) {
    int input;
    while(true) {
        cin >> input;
        // Check if the input is valid else quit the loop.
        if(input == valid) {
            Tekma newStruct = {input};
            tekme.push(newStruct);
        }
        else {
            // Stop the loop
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<Tekma> tekme;
    vpis(tekme);
    cout << najvec_kosev(tekme).prejetih; // This fixes your error.
}
```